# PHP Function with Optional Parameters

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing

I've written a PHP function that can accept 10 parameters, but only 2 are required. Sometimes, I want to define the eighth parameter, but I don't want to type in empty strings for each of the parameters until I reach the eighth.

One idea I had was to pass an abstracted function with an array of parameters which passes it along to the real function.

Is there a better way to set up the function so I can pass in only the parameters I want?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112913

Comment: That's strange. Built-in functions in php may have optional parameters. So why can't we build functions like that?

Comment: Note that **many of these answers are OUTDATED**... PHP now supports [functions with **variable-length argument lists**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Make the function take one parameter: an array. Pass in the actual parameters as values in the array.

---

*Edit:* [the link in Pekka's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112913) just about sums it up.

Comment: That's strange. Built-in functions in php may have optional parameters. So why can't we build functions like that?

Comment: @Rodrigo it's absolutely doable to define functions like those. They're positional optional though, which is pretty lousy for anything beyond a single optional parameter.

Comment: Ok, I was trying with [ ], now I see how to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34869/1086511

Comment: There is more that can be done that just the "use an array" suggestion - take a look at Walf's answer to [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690599/any-way-to-specify-optional-parameter-values-in-php/32098964#32098964) and the more in-depth example in the same thread

Answer (score 74):

What I have done in this case is pass an array, where the key is the parameter name, and the value is the value.

```
$optional = array(
  "param" => $param1,
  "param2" => $param2
);

function func($required, $requiredTwo, $optional) {
  if(isset($optional["param2"])) {
    doWork();
  }
}
```

Comment: For your example, wouldn't $optional need to be set global within the function?

Comment: global? no..? You create that array before you call the function, and you pass it. My code is an example of Matt Balls description of what should be done.

Comment: There is more that can be done that just the "use an array" suggestions - take a look at Walf's answer to [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690599/any-way-to-specify-optional-parameter-values-in-php/32098964#32098964) and the more in-depth example in the same thread

Answer (score 58):

To accomplish what you want, use an array [Like Rabbot said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978929/php-function-with-optional-parameters/3978975#3978975) (though this can become a pain to document/maintain if used excessively). Or just use the traditional optional args.

```
//My function with tons of optional params
function my_func($req_a, $req_b, $opt_a = NULL, $opt_b = NULL, $opt_c = NULL)
{
  //Do stuff
}
my_func('Hi', 'World', null, null, 'Red');
```

However, I usually find that when I start writing a function/method with that many arguments - more often than not it is a code smell, and can be re-factored/abstracted into something much cleaner.

```
//Specialization of my_func - assuming my_func itself cannot be refactored
function my_color_func($reg_a, $reg_b, $opt = 'Red')
{
  return my_func($reg_a, $reg_b, null, null, $opt);
}
my_color_func('Hi', 'World');
my_color_func('Hello', 'Universe', 'Green');
```

Comment: On 2010, notions such as 'code smell', 'refactoring' or 'code maintenance'  were not popular in our community. You had a step before most of us :)

Answer (score 23):

You can just set the default value to null.

```
<?php
function functionName($value, $value2 = null) {
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: The best answer, but please replace `null` with the non-bits of the date type. for example `array()` for arrays

Answer (score 18):

Starting with `PHP 8` you are able to use [named arguments](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params):

```
function namedParameters($paramOne, $paramTwo, $paramThree = 'test', $paramFour = null)
{
    dd($paramOne, $paramTwo, $paramThree, $paramFour);
}
```

We can now call this function with the `required` params and **only** the optinal params, that we want to differ from the `default` value which we specified in the function.

```
namedParameters('one', 'two', paramFour: 'four');
```

Result:

```
// "one", "two", "test", "four"
```

Comment: This is the best solution especially when you are dealing with existing code/functions.  Hard to change parameters into an array for functions used all over the codebase.

Comment: This should be the answer. No hacks or workarounds, just straight forward answer. With the deprecation of anything less that php 8.0 this is the answer.

Answer (score 17):

In PHP 5.6 and later, argument lists may include the ... token to denote that the function accepts a variable number of arguments. The arguments will be passed into the given variable as an array; for example:

Example Using ... to access variable arguments

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
10
```

[Variable-length argument lists PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new)

Comment: This response deserves more points. Not suitable for my specific case scenario but good information and simple to understand.

PHP 7.3 is coming shortly! 5.6 and 7 are EOL.

Answer (score 13):

*NOTE: This is an old answer, for **PHP 5.5** and below. PHP 5.6+ supports default arguments*

In PHP 5.5 and below, you can achieve this by using one of these 2 methods:

- using the **func_num_args()** and **func_get_arg()** functions;
- using NULL arguments;

### How to use

```
function method_1()
{
  $arg1 = (func_num_args() >= 1)? func_get_arg(0): "default_value_for_arg1";
  $arg2 = (func_num_args() >= 2)? func_get_arg(1): "default_value_for_arg2";
}

function method_2($arg1 = null, $arg2 = null)
{
  $arg1 = $arg1? $arg1: "default_value_for_arg1";
  $arg2 = $arg2? $arg2: "default_value_for_arg2";
}
```

I prefer the second method because it's clean and easy to understand, but sometimes you may need the first method.

Comment: You need the double "=" here or all the expressions will return true. Also, the expressions in the 2nd example will always return true because a variable is always equal to itself.

Comment: good point, but this actually works. In PHP this code `$x = null; if ($x) echo "true"; else echo "false";` will print "false", even if the $x var having a value ("null" in this code). Also, in both methods we are using the ternary operator, so it's correct use just one "=". If you test with `method(); method(1); method(1, 2);`, then the first call will associate arg1 and arg2 with the defaults values, the second call will associate the second arg with the default value and "1" for the first arg. The last call will not associate default values.

Comment: function method_2($arg1 = "default_value_fot_arg1", $arg2 =  "default_value_fot_arg2")
{
so php deal with parameter stuff and also you may pass null as parameter (why people use null I dont know)

Comment: @nerkn, you're right, PHP currently supports default arguments. Lol, I remember when we needed to make a lot of workarounds to achieve simple things. Good times :P You can still see those approaches in old codes (pre-5.5), although.

Answer (score 4):

I think, you can use objects as params-transportes, too.

```
$myParam = new stdClass();
$myParam->optParam2 = 'something';
$myParam->optParam8 = 3;
theFunction($myParam);

function theFunction($fparam){      
  return "I got ".$fparam->optParam8." of ".$fparam->optParam2." received!";
}
```

Of course, you have to set default values for "optParam8" and "optParam2" in this function, in other case you will get "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$optParam2"

If using arrays as function parameters, I like this way to set default values:

```
function theFunction($fparam){
   $default = array(
      'opt1' => 'nothing',
      'opt2' => 1
   );
   if(is_array($fparam)){
      $fparam = array_merge($default, $fparam);
   }else{
      $fparam = $default;
   }
   //now, the default values are overwritten by these passed by $fparam
   return "I received ".$fparam['opt1']." and ".$fparam['opt2']."!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function yourFunction($var1, $var2, $optional = Null){
   ... code
}
```

You can make a regular function and then add your optional variables by giving them a default Null value.

A Null is still a value, if you don't call the function with a value for that variable, it won't be empty so no error.

Comment: Can you explain all that further? The given code is syntactically invalid, as variable names cannot start with a number

Answer (score 2):

If only two values are required to create the object with a valid state, you could simply remove all the other optional arguments and provide setters for them (unless you dont want them to changed at runtime). Then just instantiate the object with the two required arguments and set the others as needed through the setter.

Further reading

- [Martin Fowler on Constructor vs Setter Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ConstructorVersusSetterInjection) and
- [Dependency injection through constructors or property setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503584/dependency-injection-through-constructors-or-property-setters)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but i was having a problem like the OP and this is what i came up with.

Example of array you could pass. You could re order this if a particular order was required, but for this question this will do what is asked.

```
$argument_set = array (8 => 'lots', 5 => 'of', 1 => 'data', 2 => 'here');
```

This is manageable, easy to read and the data extraction points can be added and removed at a moments notice anywhere in coding and still avoid a massive rewrite. I used integer keys to tally with the OP original question but string keys could be used just as easily. In fact for readability I would advise it.

Stick this in an external file for ease

```
function unknown_number_arguments($argument_set) {

    foreach ($argument_set as $key => $value) {

        # create a switch with all the cases you need. as you loop the array 
        # keys only your submitted $keys values will be found with the switch. 
        switch ($key) {
            case 1:
                # do stuff with $value
                break;
            case 2:
                # do stuff with $value;
                break;
            case 3:
                # key 3 omitted, this wont execute 
                break;
            case 5:
                # do stuff with $value;
                break;
            case 8:
                # do stuff with $value;
                break;
            default:
                # no match from the array, do error logging?
                break;
        }
    }
return;
}
```

put this at the start if the file.

```
$argument_set = array();
```

Just use these to assign the next piece of data use numbering/naming according to where the data is coming from.

```
$argument_set[1][] = $some_variable;
```

And finally pass the array

```
unknown_number_arguments($argument_set);
```

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 7.1.0, type declarations can be marked nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark (?). This signifies that the value can be of the specified type or null

```
<?php
    function name(?string $varname){
        echo is_null($varname);
    }
    name();
    name('hey');
?>
```

for more info: [Click here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.nullable)

Answer (score 0):

If you are commonly just passing in the 8th value, you can reorder your parameters so it is first.  You only need to specify parameters up until the last one you want to set.

If you are using different values, you have 2 options.

One would be to create a set of wrapper functions that take different parameters and set the defaults on the others.  This is useful if you only use a few combinations, but can get very messy quickly.

The other option is to pass an array where the keys are the names of the parameters.  You can then just check if there is a value in the array with a key, and if not use the default.  But again, this can get messy and add a lot of extra code if you have a lot of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows default arguments ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)). In your case, you could define all the parameters from 3 to 8 as NULL or as an empty string "" depending on your function code. In this way, you can call the function only using the first two parameters.

For example:

```
<?php
  function yourFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3=NULL, $arg4=NULL, $arg5=NULL, $arg6=NULL, $arg7=NULL, $arg8=NULL){
echo $arg1;
echo $arg2;
if(isset($arg3)){echo $arg3;}
# other similar statements for $arg4, ...., $arg5
if(isset($arg8)){echo $arg8;}
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea... however your proposal does not solve the problem. In fact, if you add information on what argument is being echoed (e.g. by using `echo " this is arg3: " . $arg3;`, etc., you will see that calling e.g. `yourFunction(3, 2, $arg8=5);` will print `32 this is arg3: 5`. The problem is that the parameter position still matters when passing optional parameters in PHP... parameter names _are not enough_ to map parameter values to parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

Just set Null to ignore parameters that you don't want to use and then set the parameter needed according to the position.

```
 function myFunc($p1,$p2,$p3=Null,$p4=Null,$p5=Null,$p6=Null,$p7=Null,$p8=Null){
    for ($i=1; $i<9; $i++){
        $varName = "p$i";
        if (isset($$varName)){
            echo $varName." = ".$$varName."<br>\n";
        }
    }
}   

myFunc( "1", "2", Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, "eight" );
```

Answer (score -4):

```
func( "1", "2", default, default, default, default, default, "eight" );
```

Comment: This is not valid PHP. `default` is a [keyword in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).