# PHP How assign value to some default function arguments

Tags: php, arguments, default-arguments

In following function we have some arguments with default value, How can I call that function with assigning value to some of them.

```
function foo($a, $b='def b', $c='def c', $d='def d'){
   //....
}
//call foo for $a='nu a' and $c='nu c'
foo('nu a', $c='nu c'); //but b will be assigned
```

I want to set value for `$c` and don't want to assign all of them just for `$c`.

1. Not acceptable solution:

   `foo('nu a', 'def b', 'nu c');`
2. Not acceptable solution

   `//moving c to second argument
   function foo($a, $c='def c', $b='def b', $d='def d'){  }`

So argument is after some default arguments and I don't want to set default value for previous arguments just for one

Comment: is it possible to move all the possible defaults to the right of the function arguments ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Function with Optional Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978929/php-function-with-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You're looking for named parameters which is not supported by php.

If you want to do this, you'll have to change your parameter to a single array, and in the function body extract what you need based on the keys.

Other than that, you cannot pass on a value of variable c without passing in b.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to "skip" an argument other than to specify a default like `false`, `''` or `null`.

You will use something like this:

```
function foo($settings) {
   $a = $settings['a'];
   $b = $settings['b'];
   $c = $settings['c'];
   $d = $settings['d'];
   # code...
}

foo($settings = array(
    'a' => null,
    'b' => 'def b',
    'c' => 'def c',
    'd' => 'def d',
));
```

Or, in an indexed array, you're able to use `list()` construct to handle array values, like this :

```
function foo($settings) {
   list($a, $b, $c, $d) = $settings;
   # code...
}

foo(array(null, 'def b', 'def c', 'def d'));
```

At the very least you can move whatever you think is not expected most of the time to the end of the argument list in the function definition.

```
function foo($a, $b = 'def b', $c = 'def c', $d = 'def b') {
   # code...
}
foo($a = 'def a');
```