# PHP Default parameter values: How does the compiler know which passed parameter-value is for which parameter?

Tags: php, function, default-value, default-arguments

In the following snippet, how does `printPhrase` know if the passed arguments are `$a` and `$b` (so it uses default value of `$c`, or `$a` and `$c` (so it uses default value of `$b`)?

```
private function printPhrase ($a, $b='black', $c='candle!' ) {
  echo $a . $b . $c; //Prints A black cat! or A black candle!
}

private function callprintPhrase () {
  printPhrase('A ', ' cat!');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php arguments always passes from left to right with out skip. So `printPhrase('A ', ' cat!');` always fills with values first and second argument of function.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

There is exists [proposal](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/skipparams) to skip params.

If you want to use default params you need to rewrite your code like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9541822/1503018

Answer (score 0):

```
private function callprintPhrase () {
  printPhrase('A ', ' cat!');
}
```

since you have passed 2 arguments they will be considered as arguments for $a and $b. So it will possible print something like `A cat candle!` You need to pass null value in the second argument if it is to take the value of $b i.e.

```
private function callprintPhrase () {
      printPhrase('A ','', ' cat!');
    }
```

This will give you an output A black cat!

Comment: Just to be sure, do default arguments *also replace* the `null` or empty string values explicitly passed?

Comment: yes they do. empty strings get replaced and the same applies even if you explicitly pass **null**

Comment: *This will give you an output A black cat!* -- will not.

Comment: @sectus Why not, when we are saying `''` gets replaced by the default value?

Comment: @Zarah, default value cannot replace any value: `15`, `null`, `stdClass` or whatever. If you have passed value this value would be passed to function body.