# Calling functions with multiple variables

Tags: php, function

This seems a basic question I know but I've not been able to find the answer.

Let's assume a basic function:

```
function basicFunction ( $var1, $var2 = 1, $var3 = 2, $var4 = 5 )
{
// Do some stuff
// Return
}
```

Now let's assume I want to call that function with the following variables:

```
$var1 = 0

$var2 = 1

$var3 = 2

$var4 = 3
```

I can do this:

```
$someResult = basicFunction( 0, 1, 2, 3 );
```

`$var2` and `$var3` are already set though, so how would I call the function without having to repeat the value for `$var2` and `$var3`?

Comment: You move $var2 and $var3 to the right, and call basicFunction(0, 3). Keep the optional parameters at the right end.

Comment: this is not a solution to his problem

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble : Why is it not a solution ?

Comment: It will not be flexible for usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP does not support overloading. Therefore, you cannot skip them in any way if you don't move them to the very right of the list of arguments.

A common solution is to set a default value of a different type than expected (i.e. NULL). The actual default value is then set within the function. This approach is not really clean and takes some extra lines of code, but if the situation requires it, you can go with this:

```
function basicFunction($var1, $var2 = NULL, $var3 = NULL, $var4 = NULL) {
    if ($var2 === NULL) {
        $var2 = 1;
    }

    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with PHP 8 now, see this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997399/519333

---

Old answer:

```php
function my_function(
    $id,
    $start = 0,
    $limit = 10,
    $filter = false,
    $include_duplicates => false,
    $optimize_fetch => false,
    $cache = false
) {
    if (is_array($id)) extract($id, EXTR_IF_EXISTS);

    /* ... */
}
```

And then

```php
my_function(array('id' => 1, 'cache' => true));
```

Source: http://www.marco.org/2008/11/11/faking-named-parameters-in-php

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this function that lets you call a function by an associative array. I've only tested it on scalar types though, but it should work fine for functions which take in `ints`, `floats`, `strings`, and `booleans`. I wrote this quite fast and it can definitely be improved in more ways than one:

```
function call_user_func_assoc($function, $array){
    $matches = array();
    $result = array();
    $length = preg_match_all('/Parameter #(\d+) \[ <(required|optional)> \$(\w+)(?: = (.*))? ]/', new ReflectionFunction($function), $matches);

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        if(isset($array[$matches[3][$i]]))
            $result[$i] = $array[$matches[3][$i]];
        else if($matches[2][$i] == 'optional')
            $result[$i] = eval('return ' . $matches[4][$i] . ';');
        else
            throw new ErrorException('Missing required parameter: $' . $matches[3][$i]);         
    }

    call_user_func_array($function, $result);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
function basicFunction($var1, $var2 = "default string", $var3 = 2, $var4 = 5){
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}

call_user_func_assoc('basicFunction', array('var1' => "Bob", 'var4' => 30));
```

Which outputs:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Bob"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "default string"
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(30)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think php works like that.
If you are changing `$var4` you have to include `$var2` and `$var3` becuase they come before `$var4` in the function declaration.

you could pass an array to the function with the default values and only change the `$var4` value, or change the order as nickb suggested.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

[Any way to specify optional parameter values in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690599/any-way-to-specify-optional-parameter-values-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `$var2` and `$var3` at the end of the parameter list

```
function basicFunction ( $var1, $var4 = 5, $var2 = 1, $var3 = 2)
```

Now you can call:

```
basicFunction( 0, 3);
```

Otherwise you will have to specify all of the parameters. When calling functions, you must specify all of the parameters from left to right. The only time you can omit parameters is:

1. If the parameter you want to omit has a default value.
2. All of the parameters to the right of the current parameter have default values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of passing the variables as an array in some way?
In that case you only include the variables you need to update

```
function basicFunction ( $arrayvar ){
    $arrayvar['var1']...
```

Update: Also you might use the `func_get_args()`-function that works like [the first feature here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/9-useful-php-functions-and-features-you-need-to-know/)

Answer (score 0):

More pure code 4 you (working 100%, php>5.3), working with classes and functions.

```
  function call_user_func_assoc($function, $array){
    if ((is_string($function)) && (count(explode('::',$function))>1))
        $function = explode('::',$function);

    $func = ((is_array($function)) || (count($function)>1)) ? new ReflectionMethod($function[0], $function[1]) : new ReflectionFunction($function);

    foreach($func->getParameters() as $key => $param) {
        if (isset($array[$key]))
            $result[$key] = $array[$key];
        elseif(isset($array[$param->name]))
            $result[$key] = $array[$param->name];
        else
            $result[$key] = $param->getDefaultValue();
    }
    return call_user_func_array($function, $result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to skip the values try like this

```
     $someResult = basicFunction( 0, 0, 0, 3 );
```

or if u have the values set then

```
       // passing values stored in var2,var3

       $var1 = 1;
       $var2 = 2;

    $someResult = basicFunction( 0, $var1, $var2, 3 );
```

Comment: how would assigning those values the value of 0 skip them?

Comment: i did it according to the question otherwise it would have been $var and whatever its value then .

Comment: @dm03514  Pass a null value to any argument you don't want to specify. Not really getting around it, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned by the comment above, you should always keep the optional variables on the right end, because php arguments evaluated from left to right. However, for this case you can do some trick to get rid of duplicate values as follows:

```
$var2 = 1, $var3 = 2, $var4 = 5;
function basicFunction($var1, $var2 = null, $var3 = null, $var4 = null) {
    if($var2 === null)
        $var2 = $GLOBALS["var2"];
    if($var3 === null)
        $var3 = $GLOBALS["var3"];
    if($var4 === null)
        $var4 = $GLOBALS["var4"];
}
```

However, you had better solve this situation by relocating you arguments cleverly.